# Operations on timestamp with nanoseconds in Python

Tags: python, timestamp

I have this timestamp with 9 decimal digits:

```
2019-08-05T00:01:23.486000061Z
```

I need to subtract to this timestamp a quantity like this (in seconds):

```
1.069422832374933
```

I can do this with "normal" timestamps (with 6 decimal digits) with datetime, but how can i do that in this particular case? As you can see, i also need to truncate the quantity because it has extra digits which i don't need.

Edit: i realized i can truncate the quantity using `round(float_number, 9)`

Edit: i need to obtain a timestamp with the same shape (9 digits for seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what you wanted. If it is to present this timestamp with 6 digits for seconds and no further calculation you can treat everything as a regular expression.

```
import re

givenDate = '2019-08-05T00:01:23.486000061Z'
exp       = '(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})?T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{6})'

newDate = re.search(exp, givenDate).groups()
print(newDate[0]+'-'+newDate[1]+'-'+newDate[2]+''+newDate[3]+':'+newDate[4]+':'+newDate[5]+'.'+newDate[6])
```

The output is:

2019-08-0500:01:23.486000

To obtain 9 digits is as easy as doing this:

```
exp       = '(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})?T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{9})'
```